# Passing 2 different type to single method

Tags: c#, .net, generics, ado.net

Below is my common method which will accept data reader for both MySQL and MSSQL so I want to create below method as generic and would like to use it in Generic method.

I have 2 classes from where this below method will be called:

```
Public class mysql
{
    MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    Generic(reader);
}

Public class sqlserver
{
    SqlDataReader reader = devCmd.ExecuteReader();
    Generic(reader);
}


 public void Generic() // so how to specify generic parameter
        {
          //use here
          While(dataReader.Read())
          {

          }
        }
```

So I would like to keep Generic method common for both MySQL and MSSQL which will accept data reader and will loop on to it.

Comment: @GoneCoding:Can you please provide that in the form of answer so that i can implement in that way??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need generics in this case, both implement [`IDataReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatareader(v=vs.110).aspx) interface, so use that as your parameter

```
public void Generic(IDataReader dataReader) // so how to specify generic parameter
{
   //use here
   while(dataReader.Read())
   {

   }
}
```

Comment: You added 1 comment but deleted later on like you said this is not the way to implement rdbms.Can you tell me what was it??

Comment: @Learning sorry I dont follow - what is your question?

Comment: you have written 1 comment in which you agree with @GoneCoding for implementing interface.So how i should implement this as interface??

Comment: Ah right. Yes. The answer to that is massively too broad to write in a SO answer. Look around the web for how common ORM tools support multiple different database types for more info.

Comment: Sorry but this is not working means that i have records in my data reader but then in my generic method it shows "enumeration yeilds no result"

Comment: @Learning that has nothing to do with this answer. Its somethig wrong in your data reader.

Comment: Yes you are right.Thank you so much for the answer and please keep helping like this :)